# How to automate sabre red workspace for creating a PNR

Tags: sabre

I need help to create a sabre PNR using any automation tool for automation testing recently I have tried in UTF but it's not working out so I need some help on the tool suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a Red App: https://developer.sabre.com/tools/Red_App/

> Use the Sabre Red Workspace Developer Toolkit to develop Red Apps for
>   your agency and for the travel industry's first B2B app marketplace.
>
> Hundreds of thousands of travel agents around the world use the Sabre®
>   Red Workspace to shop, book and service travel reservations for their
>   customers. Using the Sabre® Red App technology, including the Sabre
>   Red Workspace Developer Toolkit, you can build apps that integrate
>   directly into an agent’s Sabre® Red Workspace.
>
> The Sabre Red Workspace Developer Toolkit integrates with Eclipse IDE,
>   created to facilitate Red App development. What you’ll find in the
>   toolkit:
>
> - Runtime
> - Tools
> - Technical documentation
> - Sample code (25+ APIs)
> - Red App Wizards
>
> Get started with the Sabre Red Workspace Developer Toolkit by becoming
>   a Red App Certified Provider! Visit our About page on
>   sabreredappcentre.com.